# call function after react-router-redux push

Tags: internet-explorer, reactjs, react-router, redux

In my app I have a  modal with a form that once submitted successfully needs to change the route and close the modal (in that order).
The code below is working fine in all browsers but ie and edge where it will simply change the route and never close the modal or call the closeModal function. `Store.pushRoute` is just push from react-router-redux. I know I could edit store to take a callback but I am wondering if there is another way to do this without editing the store component.

```
onSuccess(formData, formObject){
    store.pushRoute(`/${this.props.team_id}/${workspaceId}`);
    this.closeModal();
}
```

Comment: What does this do? `this.closeAddWorkspace();`

Comment: oops changed it to closeModal

Comment: what does it do though?

Comment: it call a function that changes a state in redux

Comment: I mean put the function in your question... you say it never closes the modal so maybe something in the function isn't working correctly...

Comment: The function closeModal never gets called, even if its just a console.log

Comment: but `store.pushRoute` does?? If that's the case you must be getting a console error

Comment: Im not this is the weird thing, in every other browser it works in ie when it changes routes it wont execute the last function closeModal

Comment: Well you don't have enough code in your example to trouble shoot your problem.